# SQLite Format Datetime with Offset

Tags: datetime, sqlite, datetimeoffset

I want to only return the date from a datetime column in sqlite3. The problem is I have to have the offset in it. The column is called ClientCreatedDate and the value is `2011-10-24 20:53:15 +0000`

Normally, if the value looked like this `2011-10-24 20:53:15`, I would just do:

```
Select strftime('%Y-%m-%d', ClientCreatedDate) as convertedDate From Sl_Task
```

And everything would work great.

Is there anything I can do since I have the offset?

```
2011-10-24 20:53:15 +0000
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using substring

```
Select strftime('%Y-%m-%d', substr(ClientCreatedDate,1,19) as ....
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not well-documented on sqlite.org, but [the date/time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) do indeed accept timezone offsets (in which case the time is converted to UTC).

```
> SELECT DATETIME('2012-01-07 13:51:40 -06:00');
2012-01-07 19:51:40
```

But the colon between hours and minutes is required.